# Discord receive audio

Tags: python-3.x, audio, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, discord.py

I want to receive Audio from Discord to make a speech recognition. I haven't found something in the python Discord APi. The speech recognition is no problem, but I have no idea how to receive Audio from Discord. Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality doesn't really exist.  There is a [`VoiceClient.poll_voice_ws`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.poll_voice_ws) coroutine, but that [just reads directly from the socket](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/voice_client.py#L266). You'll have to come up with some way of decoding that into audio and further handling it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

A recent update to the discord.py fork pycord added the possibility to record audio, which you could then use for speech recognition.
To start recording the audio, you simply need to call `VoiceClient.start_recording` with a `Sink`, a function that will be called after you stopped recording, and optional arguments for that function. An example would be:

```py
import discord

bot = discord.Bot(debug_guilds=[719996466290098180])

@bot.command()
async def start_record(ctx):
    await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect() # Connect to the voice channel of the author
    ctx.voice_client.start_recording(discord.sinks.MP3Sink(), finished_callback, ctx) # Start the recording
    await ctx.respond("Recording...") 

async def finished_callback(sink, ctx):
    # Here you can access the recorded files:
    recorded_users = [
        f"<@{user_id}>"
        for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()
    ]
    files = [discord.File(audio.file, f"{user_id}.{sink.encoding}") for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()]
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Finished! Recorded audio for {', '.join(recorded_users)}.", files=files) 

@bot.command()
async def stop_recording(ctx):
    ctx.voice_client.stop_recording() # Stop the recording, finished_callback will shortly after be called
    await ctx.respond("Stopped!")


bot.run(Token)
```

Because this is not an audio stream, you can't use it to make a virtual assistant that will automatically listen to you, but you can record the voice channel and get what was said in it.

Comment: I have been looking into this in recent days.  Looking at the VoiceClient API for pycord, how does `unpack_audio` feed into this?