# Python voice recognition commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello actually i have no idea this works or not so just asking. Is it possible to make bot works with voice recognition along with typing commands. example below code reply's with `Pong` when someone type `!ping`  so is it possible to make it work when someone speak `ping` it should reply with `Pong`

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350976/discord-receive-audio).  Short answer: no.

Comment: So it's not possible to make it work for voice recognition.  i don't need reply in voice from bot but just i need normal reply which is in `msg = "Pong"` when we say `ping`

Comment: It's not impossible, there's just no builtin support for it.  You would have to poll the socket for bytes, interpret whatever encoding they're using into meaningful data, then stream that to some speech recognition program.  You would then have to run the text from that speech recognition through some analysis to pick out commands/keywords.  That's a pretty big project.  Some googling led me to [this](https://github.com/iCrazyBlaze/BlazeBot/blob/master/cogs/speech.py), but that doesn't appear to get audio from discord, but a local mic instead.

Comment: It is part of the TODO list for the rewrite branch of `discord.py` so might be implemented in future. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/projects/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord receive audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350976/discord-receive-audio)

Comment: This is now possible in a discord.py fork, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70987539/14506951) answer