# How can i find out if a person is currently talking in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py, voice-recognition

I would like to know whether somebody is talking or is AFK.
I have found some examples of things that might help, but I don't quite if it is even supposed to work. Like this one:

```py
async def on_member(member):
    if member.voice:
        print("HI")
```

And i would like to know if i have to import something else because currently i only have:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided returns a [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState), which you could potentially use. If you have an AFK voice channel and push-to-talk voice channel set up in your guild, you could do something like this:

(Read up about `on_voice_state_update()` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update))

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    user = f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}"
    if cur.afk and not prev.afk:
        print(f"{user} went AFK!")
    elif prev.afk and not cur.afk:
        print(f"{user} is no longer AFK!")
    elif cur.self_mute and not prev.self_mute: # Would work in a push to talk channel
        print(f"{user} stopped talking!")
    elif prev.self_mute and not cur.self_mute: # As would this one
        print(f"{user} started talking!")
```

## Clarifying:

[Discord doesn't receive audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350976/discord-receive-audio), unless you're planning on working with the bytes from the socket, but that's quite a sizeable project.

Comment: thank you very much i'll try it out in about 3 to 5 hours

Comment: thank you very much but as i said i would like to only get the information if someone is currently talking. I would like to code the rest on my own so that i really can understand whats going on with the code

Comment: there is like that green circle around a user if she's/he's talking. i just want to get that state into my code somehow