# Discord.py see if user is talking in voice

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is there a way to check whether a user in a voice channel is currently speaking or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There isn't a way to directly tell from the docs if a user is speaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350976/discord-receive-audio), unless you're planning on working with the bytes from the socket, but that's not the easiest thing to do.

If you have a push-to-talk voice channel set up in your guild, you could do something like this using the user's mute states:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if cur.self_mute and not prev.self_mute:
        print(f"{member} stopped talking!")
    elif prev.self_mute and not cur.self_mute:
        print(f"{member} started talking!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_voice_state_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)
- [`discord.VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState)